# After delete, uploading many files with maxNumberOfFiles options

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I use jQuery File Upload + jQuery File Upload UI.

My problem simple example:

1. I set option maxNumberOfFiles: 5
2. Then I added 7 files to queue.
3. Next I canceled 2 first files from the queue.
4. I clicked a send button.

Result:
After that jQuery File Upload sends only 3 first files from the queue. It seems that plugin still remembers all files even though I canceled selected.

Comment: That super-heavy library is a _mess_. It just makes everything complicated.

Comment: I think the library doesn't update the queue after canceled selected, it ought to recheck errors again in the queue, but errors connected with the  maximum number of files are still on files with exceeding number limit before cancellation.